# VirtualBox USB proxy error

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

Using VirtualBox 4.1.12, as packaged in Ubuntu 12.04, I'm unable to use USB 1.1 device (a Canon FS-4000US scanner) within a Win XP VM. I'm able to connect other USB devices, such as a USB flash drive, fine, yet the scanner gives:

```
Failed to attach the USB device Canon Scanner [1001] to the virtual machine WinXP.

Failed to create a proxy device for the USB device. (Error:VERR_READ_ERROR).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component: Console

Interface: IConsole {1968b7d3-e3bf-4ceb-99e0-cb7c913317bb}
```

As follows from other devices working, I'm in the `vboxusers` group. Any ideas?

Comment: **Note: please pastebin the output of `lsmod`**. 0x80004005 in most contexts is a permissions error or file not found error (that presents as permissions). that error code is a blanket for "i tried to read something but couldn't". if you want to see what i mean back up your vbox xml and change a disk-id to something that doesn't exist or change the permissions on a disk to root only.

Comment: @izx http://pastebin.com/KaPGTZBa (will incorporate into question if any of it turns out to be relevant; don't see anything there myself)

Answer (score 0):

Some things that helped me:

- Disable USB3 ("XHCI") temporarily in BIOS/UEFI system settings. Some instructions hint on using different USB port (eg. one with only USB2 support), but that did not help me.
- Edit/add temporarily /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-local.conf and add lines "blacklist usb_storage" and "blacklist keucr" to it. Reboot, but note you'll lose access to any USB storage like it says.

After that I was able to mount a SD card reader in VirtualBox, even without USB filter as such but just selecting it from the USB menu during runtime.

Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (3.11 kernel), Asus Z87 motherboard, latest VirtualBox.